# How to search the database for some characters and get the total count

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to query the database for some characters and get the count of each character. Here is the query I have for getting the occurrence of each character:

```
SPOOL /tmp/special_char_count.xls  
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000 
SET LINESIZE 9999
SET PAGESIZE 50000
DECLARE match_count INTEGER;
TYPE bin_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
spec_char_array bin_array;

BEGIN
   spec_char_array(1) := 'k';
   spec_char_array(2) := 't';


   FOR i IN 1 .. spec_char_array.COUNT 
     LOOP
       FOR t IN 
       (select owner,table_name, column_name, DATA_TYPE from dba_tab_columns where owner like 'SCOTT' and DATA_TYPE not in ('FLOAT', 'DATE', 'NUMBER', 'TIMESTAMP(6)') )

  LOOP
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ||
        ' WHERE '||t.column_name||' like ''%'||spec_char_array(i)||'%''' 
        INTO match_count ;

     IF match_count > 0 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line( t.table_name ||chr(9)||t.column_name||chr(9)||spec_char_array(i)||chr(9)||match_count);
     END IF;

    END LOOP;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
SPOOL OFF
```

How can I get the total count of all characters from the above query? I am spooling it to an excel file thinking I can use the Sum function in spread sheet. When I get the excel file from linux to windows, it says the file is corrupted when I try to open and I don't see the Sum function working. I am thinking of getting the total count with the query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get a character count from an entire database, table, or column?

Comment: Querying the entire database and getting counts of the characters from each table columns.